# Jenkins slave is not accessing chrome in GUI

Tags: google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, jenkins, headless-browser, jenkins-agent

I have my selenium automation script running in chrome and it is running through Jenkins. I have two machines in Jenkins, one master, and one slave, both of them are Windows 2012 R2.

While running in master, the automation script is working fine and I can see the script opening a chrome browser in the master remote machine, but while it is running in Slave, I don't see any chrome opening in the slave machine. Looks like it is automatically opening a headless browser and running the script in the background. Unfortunately, the browser is too small (with scrollbars) and a lot of buttons are out of the window.

Is there any way to turn off that automatic headless run and allow slave to actually open the chrome browser?

Note: I have connected to slave via jnlp (Java method).

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the browser opened in another user. You can verify that by opening Task Manager to see all process, you will notice there is a chrome process but run under another user.

I don't know the rule Jenkins determine to use which user to running your script. You can try connect slave under different user to see anything you can found to resolve your problem.

Comment: But why is the browser not expanding (maximizing) to the set size while running on another user? It uses weird vertical and horizontal scroll bar to cover the page, I have put specific code to maximize it which works on master (same type of Windows machine) but not working on slave. Is that something that I can change?